# Issue on Validating Confirmation Pass Key

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble on validating link for confirmation email. I can send users a confirmation link from my database as an HTML email like this

```
$msg = "
<a href=\"http://asite.ca/assets/functions/confirmation.php?key=$permissionCode\"  target=\"_blank\">Click To Confirm</a>
";
```

the `$permissionCode` is generating like this

```
$permissionCode = substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 12);
```

which I inserted in `confirm_code` field.

and 
 in my confirmation.php I have

```
$key    = $_Get["key"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = $key";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "We Will Contact You Soon";

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

but I am getting the `0 results` while the same code of the link is in the database when users click the confirmation link in their email! can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: `$_Get` -> `$_GET` Maybe...?

Comment: Thanks but same! I changed the get to GET but same thing happening!

Comment: `= '$key'`, there's a string in key, it's not an int

Comment: it is String , I am using the substr() in `$permissionCode = substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 12);` so it is a string, is,t it?

Comment: Precisely, but you're treating it as an int, with `= $key`, but if you encapsulate it in quotations, it's then treated as a string `= '$key'`

Comment: I see so how can I fix it now?

Comment: @Rizier123 Even if you write it as $_get, it will work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your $key with single quote in query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = '$key'";
```

As requested in comment, See the explanation.....

**Case 1 :**

```
$key =substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 12);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = $key';
echo $sql;
```

output is

```
SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = $key
```

Here if you see single quote does not look for a variable. Whatever is there inside '   ' is considered as a string and returned as such.

**Case 2:**

```
$key =substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 12);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = $key";
echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = dcd9c750bab0
```

Here Since the query is inside double quotes, That variable is read. but considered as int.

**Case 3:**

```
$key =substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 12);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = '$key'";
echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
SELECT * FROM `contact_request` WHERE `confirm_code` = 'fd7c159e29c6'
```

Here Since the query is inside double quotes, That variable is read. but considered as string as it is encapsulated with single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Indra, but this is one of those confusing part that when to use the '' or not?! Can you please briefly let me know when and why we should use the single quotes?

Comment: Hope you can understand the way quotes behave